# Linq left join with condition with nullable string

Tags: c#, linq

This is the query..I need to convert to linq/

```
 select *, from  agentList ag
                        inner join branchList br on ag.BranchId=br.Id
                        inner join  bankList ba on  br.BankId =ba.Id
                        left join  accounts ac 
                         on br.BrIN=ac.BranchId and  ba.BaIN = ac.BankId 
                           and ac.AIN=ac.Id   //This  NUllable in C#
```

***Linq:***

var final =

```
            from ag in agentList
            join br in branchList on ag.BranchId equals br.Id
            join ba in bankList on br.BankId equals ba.Id
            join ac in accounts on new { ag.Id, br.Id, ba.Id } equals new { ac.AgentId,ac.BranchId, ac.BankId } 
            
            select new 
            {
                AccountName = ac.AccountName,

            };
```

Am getting below error  because AIN is Nullable string

[image]

Beacuse UAN in nullable string .. How to left join with naullable properties in condtion

---

EDIT:

***Linq:***

```
var query =
    from ag in agentList
    join br in branchList on ag.BranchId equals br.Id
    join ba in bankList on br.BankId equals ba.Id
    join ac in accounts on new { br.BrIN, ba.BaIN } equals new { ac.BranchId ,ac.BankId }
    into details
    from a in details.Where(a => a.UIN = details.AgentId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        details.Id
    };
```

Am getting below error  because AIN is Nullable string

Beacuse UAN in nullable string .. How to left join with naullable properties in condtion

[image]

Comment: Start by giving one and the same name to the corresponding anonymous type members., as this is the first requirement, then check the types if needed. e.g. `on new { K1 = br.BrIN, K2 = ba.BaIN } equals new { K1 = ac.BranchId, K2 = ac.BankId }` See [Join by using composite keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys)

Comment: Please, next time post exceptions as text. Images are a nuisance on many devices.

Comment: Ok..@GertArnold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Am getting below error because AIN is Nullable string" - No, you're getting an error because you are creating an anonymous type with non-unique property names and you aren't matching the names in the two types you are creating.

You need something like this:

```
var final =
    from ag in agentList
    join br in branchList on ag.BranchId equals br.Id
    join ba in bankList on br.BankId equals ba.Id
    join ac in accounts
        on new
        {
            AgentId = ag.Id,
            BranchId = br.Id,
            BankId = ba.Id 
        }
        equals new
        {
            ac.AgentId,
            ac.BranchId,
            ac.BankId
        }
    select new
    {
        AccountName = ac.AccountName,
    };
```

To compare two anonymous types, the property names, types, and their order must be the same.

Comment: Thanks .but i am getting  same error  join ac in accounts in screen shot >.can u pls check

Comment: Also i have changed my query for AgentId is nullable ..

Comment: @Ajt - Please do not edit questions to invalidate existing answers. If you have a further question either add to the end of the existing one or ask a new one altogether. I've done my best fixing your question, but you may need to do some fine tuning. Please leave the basic structure though.

Comment: @Ajt - Please also understand that your newly posted query still has anonymous types that have different property names. My answer is 100% valid for both of your LINQ queries.

Comment: Thanks..last question if  AgentId = ag.Id   if AgentId  is null i have to modify or still same code works?

Comment: @Ajt - You could test it to find out, but it should work fine.